# Follow-up question to "Rmarkdown image gallery": neither pixture nor slickr displays correctly in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, slickr

I have a follow-up question to the provided solutions to

[Rmarkdown image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196767/rmarkdown-image-gallery/77325904?noredirect=1#comment136321949_77325904).

I have tried both approaches (pixture and slickr) in my R Markdown file using images stored locally on my computer. When I knit the markdown file to html, both solutions work absolutely fine.

Next, I wanted to use the R Markdown file within a shiny app, here is the code I used:

Here is my UI code:

```
tabPanel(title = "Certificates",
           tabPanel(title = "Certificate Gallery",
                    uiOutput("certificate_gallery")))
```

And here is my server code:

```
output$certificate_gallery <- renderUI({
    rmd2UI("www/Gallery_Certificates.Rmd")
  })
```

Once I run the shiny app, the app produces the following output:

- **pixture**: shiny displays an empty rectanglar, i.e. the images are not being loaded.
- **slickR**: shiny displays the first couple of images, but both the arrows and dots to click through additional images are not responsive in the app (they are both displayed, but they do not respond).

I cannot figure out how to fix this problem - can somebody help me out?

I should mention that this is the first shiny app I am building, so please keep that in mind when answering ;-)

Thanks a lot in advance,
Andrea

Comment: You can try the [swipeR](https://github.com/stla/swipeR) package. But why do you want to use a Rmarkdown file in the Shiny app?

Comment: Hi Stephane, thank you so much for your reply. I just figured out how to do it (see below), but I did take a look at the swipeR package nonetheless and it looks pretty cool! Not sure I want to change anything right now, but I will certainly keep swipeR in mind for the future. Oh, and the reason why I wanted to use the Rmarkdown file is that I am trying to create some sort of homepage with various panels and I found it easier to feed the separate panels with markdown files instead of setting everything up in long and complex UI code. Again, thanks for you help - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work:

Within the markdown file, I set up the slickr carousel:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(slickR)

paths <- c(
  "first_pic.png",
  "second_pic.png",
  "third_pic.png",
  "fourth_pic.png",
  "fifth_pic.png",
  "sixth_pic.png",
  "seventh_pic.png",
  "eight_pic.png"
)

opts <- settings(
  dots = TRUE,
  initialSlide = 0,
  slidesToShow = 1,
  slidesToScroll = 1, 
  focusOnSelect = TRUE
)

slickR(obj = paths, height = 625, width = "95%") + opts
```

Then, I used the following code in the UI:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage(
...,
 tabPanel(title = "title",
           tabPanel("html", tags$iframe(src = "markdownfile.html", width = "100%", height = 1000, style = "border:none;"))),
...
)
```